# How to redirect MirajeJS to a real request if there is no such route in mocks?

Tags: reactjs, miragejs

With the help of mirajeJS, we can simulate routes, but is it possible, if such a route is not simulated in mirajeJS, to redirect it and use a real server using axios?

```
import {Server} from "miragejs";

new Server({
  routes() {
    this.namespace = "api/";
    this.get("test/router", () => {
      return [
        {name: "Angy", surname: "T."},
        {name: "Chris", surname: "B."},
        {name: "Juliana", surname: "Crain"}
      ];
    });
  }
});
```

That is, I want to achieve the following behavior, I wet the test / router request, but if the user makes any other request that is not locked in Miraje, then it goes to the real server, that is, the real request is used

Answer (score 1):

You could use a passthrough like this

```js
new Server({
  routes() {
    this.namespace = "api/";
    this.get("test/router", () => {
      return [
        {name: "Angy", surname: "T."},
        {name: "Chris", surname: "B."},
        {name: "Juliana", surname: "Crain"}
      ];
    });
    // Allow unhandled requests on the current domain to pass through
    this.passthrough();
  }
});
```